# Prevent a Duplicate contact role on opportunity with Lightning Flow error

Tags: before-trigger, visual-flows

There are several ways to avoid/restrict creation of duplicate contacts as contact roles on opportunity using APEX triggers. I am trying to build one using the 'Before Create/Update' lightning flow

[image]

---

- I created a checkbox field on the OpportunityContact Role object called: Duplicate Assertion
- I created a Validation Rule that checks if: Duplicate Assertion it TRUE - and prevents the save.

In my 'Before Create/Update', it's a simple flow:
[image]

- Get all records from OpportuniyContactRoles where OpportunityID equals $record.opportunityID
- loop all records, if $record.contactid equals any returned entry
- The Decision rule
  [image]
- set the $record.DuplicateAssertion field to true
- The Assignment
  [image]
- The save of the newly/updarted OCR's should fail if DuplicateAssertion is TRUE.
- The issue is that it's not working. If I only test the assignment within the flow (as a test) - the records are correctly not saved.
  But if I let the process work, it saves even with a duplicate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a mistake in the Loop object.
The return arrow from the 'Assignment' object, needs to go to the Loop object, and not the 'Decision' object.

A way to identify this was also to use the 'Auto-Layout' feature. It mentioned the error, only I had to figure out what it meant.